# STL Algorithm for generating a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, std

I want to generate a vector using STL algorithm to achieve the following

```
const int N1 = 10; // This can vary
const int offset = 3; // This also can vary
std::vector<int> chans(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < chans.size(); i++)
{
    chans[i] = offset + N1*i;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=STL%20Algorithm%20for%20generating%20a%20vector

Comment: @StevenBurnap, I am aware of std::generate, but is it worth it to write a seperate function for something as simple as this. Hence, I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: Then you should say so in your question.  Don't make us guess what you have already tried and rejected.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: google is by itself not a reason not to downvote. This site is trying to be a mega resource for developers. Google is not a developer resource. We should hope that the SO content becomes the 1st google hit. That said, this is a pretty nonsense question as it fails to follow most of the guidelines on asking good questions.

Comment: FWIW: I'm not the one who downvoted.  But the question as it stands needs to better explanation of what the problem actually is.  As the question is written, "use std::generate" is a trivially correct answer that a minimal reading of STL documentation would discover.

Comment: @StevenBurnap, is std::generate the only way to do this? If so, please downvote it by all means.

Comment: @user3670482: It's never the only way.  But it's the best way.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Under the circumstances, `std::generate_n` might really be preferable (but it's not clear whether you may have included that as "part of" `std::generate`, since conceptually it sort of is).

Comment: You may also use `std::iota` ([Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b802f2509c5c8ff3)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C++14:

```
std::generate(chans.begin(), chans.end(),
    [=, count = 0]() mutable { return offset + N1 * count++; });
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c36daa1626ae66f)