# How to apply C++ std algorithms in this context?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I'm learning c++ and I would like to know how I can improve the following code:

```
std::vector<float> distances;
std::for_each(play_->get_emps().begin(), play_->get_emps().end(), [distances, tank] (const auto& e) {
    distances.push_back(math::distance(e.location(), tank->location()));
});
```

There must be a better way to fill a vector with std::algorithms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STL Algorithm for generating a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743247/stl-algorithm-for-generating-a-vector). Check out e.g. cpprefence.com before asking as part of your own research as well.

Comment: Your code wouldn't work as is, you need to capture `distances` by reference.

Comment: I would use a boost transform_iterator (or similar) so I can directly pass it to the vector's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is an algorithm which applies a function to each element in range (or two ranges) and stores result in another range (can be equal to any input range as well).

```
std::vector<float> distances;
std::transform(play_->get_emps().begin(), play_->get_emps().end(), 
               std::back_inserter(distances),
               [tank](const auto& e) {return math::distance(e.location(), tank->location();});
```

---

`<algorithm>` is all cool, but sometimes it's an overkill IMO. `for` loop would be even simpler:

```
std::vector<float> distances;
for(const auto& e: play_) {
    distances.push_back(math::distance(e.location(), tank->location()));
}
```

---

As noted by [Marc Glisse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918193/marc-glisse) in comments, both versions would benefit from call to `std::vector::reserve` beforehand. `push_back` is quite inefficient when used frequently (`std::back_inserter` uses `push_back` internally as well)

```
std::vector<float> distances;
distances.reserve(play_.size());
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. My goal is to get the `const emp_object_actor` that has the smallest location towards my `tank` object. I am currently doing that like this: https://pastebin.com/4NSqQH8e. Is that okey?

Comment: @Frogical looks good to me. You could probably do that without extra `map`, but it's pretty clean. BTW. there's also [codereview.se] for "is my code good?" type of questions - be sure to read it's help pages, I'm not a regular there and I'm not sure what questions are accepted.